# jQuery each delay and once finished callback

Tags: jquery, callback, delay, each

I'm trying to load a function after each span gets class one by one.

```js
$("span.outline").each(function (index) {
  $(this).delay(300 * index).addClass("loaded");
});
$("span.outline").promise().done(function() {
  alert("All Loaded");
});
```

```css
.outline{
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
.outline.loaded{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="outline">Span Name</span>
<span class="outline">Span Name</span>
<span class="outline">Span Name</span>
<span class="outline">Span Name</span>
```

The problem is that in the beginning all spans must be red and become blue one by one.

Alert is working correctly. It waits until each delay time is finished.

Please help me to find a solution

Comment: [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) only works for jquery animations, not as a general "wait".  You could use `setTimeout` instead.

Comment: I used `setTimeout` and it works for elements but not for alert. Alert jumps immediately

Comment: Use setTimeout for the alert as well and set the timeout so it matches the sum of the other timeouts.  As with .delay, `.promise().done` waits for *jquery animations* to complete.

Comment: Thank you I will try

Comment: This *might* help as an alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532916/run-a-callback-after-multiple-function-have-completed